# SQR 5543 error. Report arguments in sqrw

Tags: oracle, sqr

I am trying to run SQRW and it asks for report arguments.

I entered -ZIF"path to my pssqr.ini" (without the quotes)

once I hit OK I get the error (SQR 5543) Specify the Oracle DLL name in the SQR.INI file in [Environment:Oracle] section for ORACE_DLL entry, such as

ORACLE_DLL=orant71.dll

I tried to add the oracle dll bin path to my search path and I also tried added that ORACLE_DLL= to the pssqr.ini file. Neither worked but i'm not even sure which dll file I should get. There is nothing like orant71.dll in my oracle bin directory.

Which dll file do I use if i have oracle 11?

Are there any other suggestion of what I can do or what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, I fixed it by installing Oracle 10g rather than 11g. This fixed it, I don't know why though.